# I can't open Oracle raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, oracle-spatial

I can't open Oracle's raster layer in QGIS. When I load the layer it looks like this:

[image]

This layer works perfectly in Geomedia (Sisgraph), which is the software we used but we are migrating to QGIS. Can someone explain to me why it doesn't load the layer.

Comment: QGIS reads it differently to Geomedia https://geospatialcommunity.hexagon.com/s/article/Raster-Storage-in-Oracle-Object-Data-Model-for-GeoMedia - how is your raster stored in Oracle?

Comment: Mapperz, storage is done as explained in the link you shared, using a polygon vector. I had noticed this but I don't know how to store it so that I can see it in QGIS. Can you help me? Do I have to change anything in the database (gdosys or mdsys) or just create a new layer with the raster already?

Comment: I assume QGIS is expecting GeoRaster https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11827/geor_datatypes_metadata.htm#GEORS200